# Interfaces and empty classes in code coverage

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm using PHPUnit 5.2.9, PHP 5.6.19 and Xdebug 2.4.0 (non RC) alongside netbeans IDE.

Like any other project, I make use of interfaces and the odd empty extended class. Since these files contain no executable code, why are they being listed in my code coverage reports? More than that, they are listed as 0% covered with 0/0 methods. (I'd be happy if that were 100% just to see less red)

I have tried excluding them within the `phpunit.xml` file:

```
<whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false"> // true make no difference
    <directory suffix=".php">./Annotation</directory>
    <directory suffix=".php">./Cache</directory>
    <exclude>
        <directory suffix=".php">./*Interface</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">./*/*Interface</directory>
    </exclude>
</whitelist>
```

But it appears globs (*) are only valid for directories. I can however use the `<file>` tag and exclude them individually. However, that's a lot of files to exclude when they shouldn't be included in the first place.

Am I doing something wrong or is this standard behaviour?

Comment: Did you implement those interfaces? On my coverage interfaces are shown as green...

Comment: @JakubZalas Yes, they are all mine. In my mind they should be green, but they are 0% covered and in the red. Are you using netbeans and what versions of PHP Xdebug?

Answer (score 3):

You can try improved your exclusion directory as follow:

```
<exclude>
    <directory suffix="Interface.php">.</directory>
</exclude>
```

OTherwise, you can mark directly in the code proper annotation described in the Ignoring Code [Blocks of the doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks.examples.Sample.php), as follow:

```
<?php
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
interface Foo
{
    public function bar();
}
```

Or you can mark as covered the method of the interface class in the testcase, see more info [in the doc here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#appendixes.annotations.covers.tables.annotations). As example:

```
 /**
 * @test
 * @covers Bar::foo
 * @covers BarInterface::foo
 */
  public function foo()
  {
    ....
  }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Your method of exclusion works flawlessly. But, both the `@codeCoverageIgnore` and `@covers` fail to do anything. The interfaces are still included in the xml output and netbeans shows them as 0% coverage. Based on @JakubZalas' comment above, I'm thinking this is a bug within netbeans itself.

Comment: Hi  @twifty what version of phpinit are you using?

Comment: It's in the OP, 5.2.9

Comment: Hi @Twifty sorry i see now. Regards of the annotation I see issues about it referring to the PHP_CodeCoverage library, so i don't know if is due to phpunit or xdebug.